# Log in problem with ubuntu

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

My raspberry pi won't connect to putty unless I connected it to the HDMI cable, keyboard and mouse, press "log in" that appears on the screen then I'm able to to run the Pi from computer.
I'm running Ubuntu OS.

Comment: I am guessing from your question that you installed noobs. I am not sure there is a way around this other than installing Ubuntu or Raspbian directly (without noobs).

Comment: I actually installed directly :\